# is there Uber delivery API?

Tags: uber-api

I want to add feature in my app to delver products from user to another. from home to home. Can I use **Uber API** instead of building it from scratch. If so please provide me with a documentation.

I've searched in [Uber APIs Documentation](https://developer.uber.com) but I couldn't find. could you please help me??

Comment: Check out the Postmates API: https://postmates.com/developer/docs

Answer (score 0):

No- there is not an Uber delivery API. There used to be a limited API, but the overall service shut down: http://fortune.com/2018/03/31/uber-ending-uberrush-delivery-service/